# Using linked nested NPM modules for Webpack Require

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

We are using `webpack` to require resources in a project where we also use a number of sub-modules from NPM. Since we are also developing the sub-modules we use `npm link <module-name>` when working with the code.

We have one module that is required in multiple places throughout the product and sub-modules. The problem comes when trying to link this module and accessing that code from another sub-module.

In a nutshell our setup looks like this:

```
+- main-project
   +- alfa
   |  +- common
   +- bravo
   |  +- common
   +- common
```

We then use `module.exports()` together with `require()` in our code to require modules as needed.

When the `common` sub-module is published and referenced by version in the package.json file of `alfa` and `bravo` it works as intended.

I'd want to be able to use `npm link common` in the `main-project` to make the dependency hit all sub-modules as well, preferably whether or not they are linked as well.

As a foot note we are using package.json files throughout the modules that resembles the below example

```
{
  "name": "x-ray",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { ... },
  "repository": "...",
  "homepage": "https://example.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "alfa": "^1.0.9",
    "bravo": "^1.0.5",
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this a correct way of setting things up with webpack? Should we be using some other form of dependencies? Peer for example?

Comment: ... please let me know if you need any clarification. I'll be the first to recognise that I am not an expert in setting up webpack projects so I might have missed something important.

Comment: I ended up removing all my projects and cloning them from git again, and it worked. Is there any caches for webpack that I can clean or something along those lines?